# How can I remove Ubuntu without using live-cd/usb

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, boot, uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my notebook. I would like to completely remove the operating system so that my PC is in "No operating System" mode. I searched internet and the how-to's need a live-usb/cd. I want to remove it while using the same.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't remove the operating system without a live cd or 3rd party software. May I ask what the reason for wanting to do this is, what is your final goal?

Comment: The reasons are personal. As far as deleting goes, why can't we just remove/delete the partition that contains OS using GParted or so.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not possible: You can't remove the system you're currently running.

To remove Ubuntu, you *will* need a Windows Recovery CD or Installation CD, or a Ubuntu Live CD or other bootable media.

Comment: How about removing the partition?

Comment: If you remove the partition, the partition table or GPT is removed but the data is left intact.

Comment: Does that mean no one will be able to access the PC and the data it contains? Basically what I want is something similar like that. I don't care about data but I would be lucky if I could retain that data when I change my mind to install Ubuntu again- I don't expect this anyway.